# rename 'page' URL fragment in pretty permalinks

Tags: permalinks

i would like my WP URLs to be fully in my language so instead of:

`site.com/page/2/`

i would like to have:

`site.com/pagina/2/` (in spanish)

how can i accomplish this? i tried to do simple `str_replace` on default rules but when accessing `site.com/pagina/2/` WP redirects me to `site.com/pagina/2/page/2/`

any ideas what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but maybe usefull for someone else… code goes to functions.php. You have to flush your rewrite rules.

```
<?php

    // Set custom pagination_base
    function mytheme_pagination_base() {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'pagina';
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_pagination_base' );
```